# find $\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-ax}\cos({bx})dx}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I need help finding this integral.

First I solved the indefinite integral such that

$$\int{e^{-ax}\cos({bx})dx}=\frac{-ae^{-ax}cos(bx)}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{be^{-ax}sin(bx)}{a^2+b^2}+C$$

Now, secondly, evaluate the integral as follows

$$\int_{0}^{b}{e^{-ax}\cos({bx})dx}=\frac{be^{-ab}sin(b^2)-ae^{-ab}cos(b^2)+a}{a^2+b^2}$$

I suppose then that the following would still have to be found

$$\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{be^{-ab}sin(b^2)-ae^{-ab}cos(b^2)+a}{a^2+b^2}$$

So far I have that, but I don't know how to find that limit. Any help please?

Comment: What is $n$ ? There is no $n$ in your integral.  Why do you take the limit ? Why do you integrate from $0$ to $b$ ?

Comment: Why you integrated it from 0 to b?

Comment: To expand on the existing comments, you're making $b$ do too many things. Make the integral's upper limit $n$ instead of $b$, get the integral in terms of $a,\,b,\,n$, then take the $n\to\infty$ limit.

Comment: Definite integral is wrong.  x should be replaced by n, not b.  Limit is $\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}$.

Comment: It's b, I made a mistake typing the problem. It has been corrected

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a$ and $b$ real, $a>0$,
$$I=\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-ax} \mbox{Re}(e^{ibx}) dx $$
$$I=\mbox{Re}\left ( \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-ax} e^{ibx} dx \right) $$
$$I=\mbox{Re}\left ( \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{(-a+ib)x} dx \right) $$
$$I=\mbox{Re}\left ( \left [ \frac{e^{(-a+ib)x}}{-a+ib} \right]_{0}^{+\infty}  \right) $$
$$I=\mbox{Re}\left ( - \frac{1}{-a+ib} \right) $$
$$I=\mbox{Re}\left ( \frac{a+ib}{a^2+b^2} \right) $$
$$I=\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}$$

Comment: This is really enlightening...

Answer (score 0):

You can consider a pair of integrals

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_c(a, b) &= \int_0^{+\infty}e^{-ax}\cos(bx)dx \\
I_s(a, b) &= \int_0^{+\infty}e^{-ax}\sin(bx)dx
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, assuming that $a > 0$, apply integration by parts:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_c(a, b) &= \int_0^{+\infty}e^{-ax}\cos(bx)dx = \int_0^{+\infty}\underbrace{\cos(bx)}_{u}\underbrace{d\left(-\frac{1}{a}e^{-ax}\right)}_{dv} = \\
&= \underbrace{\left.\underbrace{\cos(bx)}_u\underbrace{\left(-\frac{1}{a}e^{-ax}\right)}_{v}\right|_0^{+\infty}}_{=\frac{1}{a}}-\int_0^{+\infty}\underbrace{\left(-\frac{1}{a}e^{-ax}\right)}_{v}\underbrace{d\cos(bx)}_{dv} = \\
&= \frac{1}{a} - \frac{b}{a}\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-ax}\sin(dx)dx = \frac{1}{a}-\frac{b}{a}I_s(a, b) \Leftrightarrow \\
&\Leftrightarrow I_c(a, b) + \frac{b}{a}I_s(a, b) = \frac{1}{a}
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_s(a, b) &= \int_0^{+\infty}e^{-ax}\sin(bx)dx = \int_0^{+\infty}\underbrace{\sin(bx)}_{u}\underbrace{d\left(-\frac{1}{a}e^{-ax}\right)}_{dv} = \\
&= \underbrace{\left.\underbrace{\sin(bx)}_u\underbrace{\left(-\frac{1}{a}e^{-ax}\right)}_{v}\right|_0^{+\infty}}_{=0}-\int_0^{+\infty}\underbrace{\left(-\frac{1}{a}e^{-ax}\right)}_{v}\underbrace{d\sin(bx)}_{dv} = \\
&=  \frac{b}{a}\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-ax}\cos(dx)dx = \frac{b}{a}I_c(a, b) \Leftrightarrow \\
&\Leftrightarrow -\frac{b}{a}I_c(a, b) + I_s(a, b) = 0
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, we have a system of two linear equations with two unknowns: $I_c(a, b)$ and $I_s(a, b)$:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
I_c(a, b) + \frac{b}{a}I_s(a, b) &= \frac{1}{a} \\
-\frac{b}{a}I_c(a, b) + I_s(a, b) &
= 0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

1. by multiplying the first equation by $\frac{b}{a}$ and adding the second equation, we obtain
   $$
   \frac{b^2}{a^2}I_s(a, b) + I_s(a, b) = \frac{b}{a^2} \Rightarrow I_s(a, b) = \int_0^{+\infty}e^{-ax}\sin(bx)dx = \frac{b}{a^2+b^2}
   $$
2. by multiplying the second equation by $-\frac{b}{a}$ and adding the first equation, we obtain
   $$
   I_c(a, b) + \frac{b^2}{a^2}I_c(a, b) = \frac{1}{a} \Rightarrow I_c(a, b) = \int_0^{+\infty}e^{-ax}\cos(bx)dx = \frac{a}{a^2+b^2}
   $$